# Starting process with command `gunicorn app:app` Exited with status 126

Tags: python, flask, heroku, deployment, gunicorn

I have a python flask app deployed to heroku.

After the build completes, this is the log.

```
2021-05-15T17:58:00.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user xxx
2021-05-15T17:58:39.006534+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 23e180a8 by user xxx
2021-05-15T17:58:39.006534+00:00 app[api]: Release v29 created by xxx
2021-05-15T17:58:39.356233+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-05-15T17:58:44.631213+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn app:app`
2021-05-15T17:58:46.642208+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 126
2021-05-15T17:58:46.707103+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-05-15T17:58:46.591536+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: No such file or directory
2021-05-15T17:58:49.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
```

These are the contents in my Procfile

```
web: gunicorn app:app
```

I have the main file name as app.py

And these are the requirements.txt

```
app-version==1.0.1
APScheduler==3.6.3
certifi==2020.12.5
chardet==3.0.4
click==8.0.0
Werkzeug==2.0.0
Flask==2.0.0
gunicorn==20.1.0
idna==2.8
Jinja2==3.0.0
MarkupSafe==2.0.0
notify==0.3.1
notify-run==0.0.13
PyQRCode==1.2.1
pytz==2021.1
requests==2.22.0
selenium==3.141.0
six==1.16.0
tornado==6.1
tzlocal==2.1
urllib3==1.25.11
validate-email==1.3
```

Added these using pip freeze. Any idea whats going wrong?

Comment: If you run `gunicorn app:app` on your computer what happens?

Comment: It's working. There are no errors.

Comment: Is it possible that you forgot to add to git some files, like `app.py` ?

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/run.html
Format for Procfile if you using gunicorn:
gunicorn [OPTIONS] [WSGI_APP]

"web: gunicorn app:app" - it is mean file app.py has function app that run application, and file app.py saved on root of project. Check patch.